# Communication between two activities using interface not working as expected

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin, interface, android-lifecycle

**PROBLEM:** On sending data from **activity2** to **activity1** using interface results in non-assignment of send data in **activity1** even if it is being assigned. Consequently, **activity1** members variables are automatically set to null.

**SETUP DETAIL:** On clicking a button in **activity1**, launches **activity2**. Now a user can perform whatever work in **activity2**. But as soon as a user performs work in **activity2**, my custom interface sends a data to **activity1**. Activity1 is supposed to assign that sent value to its member variable and when the user navigates back to **activity1**, ***onRestart()*** method of activity1 is bound to update user-interface with a new value.

**SETUP IN POINTS:**

**1-** User clicks a button on **ACTIVITY1**

**2-** Button opens **ACTIVITY2**

**3-** User performs an action that triggers my interface to send a data

**4-** Interface sends  data to **ACTIVITY1** in the background(ACTIVITY2 is still visible)

**5-** Sent data is assigned to **ACTIVITY1** member variable(boolean) via interface

**6-** User back presses on **ACTIVITY2** and navigates back to **ACTIVITY1**

**7-** ***ONRESTART()*** of **ACTIVITY1** gets triggered

**8-** **ONRESTART()** checks if the boolean is true, then update UI

But here my confusion starts. **Why** is the assigned boolean value still null even after being assigned? **Why**  is ACTIVITY1`s member variables losing assigned values?

**CODE:**

**Interface**

```
override fun onReturnedToActivity(actionID: Int) {
    when(actionID)
    {
        3 ->
        {
            newNoteCreated = true
        }
    }
}
```

**ONRESTART()**

```
override fun onRestart() {
    super.onRestart()

    if(newNoteCreated)  //variable is null not true.
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"TRUE",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        mDrawer!!.updateBadge(3, StringHolder(dbHandler.totalNotes().toString() ))

        newNoteCreated = false
    }
```

Please educate me on this problem. I have been trying to find its solution on SO but nothing yet answers my question. I know there are other ways to send data between activities but I am trying to particularly use interfaces.

Quoting from

> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#ActivityLifecycle

"*If an activity is completely obscured by another activity, it is stopped. **It still retains all state and member information**, however, it is no longer visible to the user so its window is hidden and it will often be killed by the system when memory is needed elsewhere.*"

Then why does my activity loses its variable data?

**EDIT**

**Main Activity(ACTIVITY1)**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ContextBarVisibilityListener, OnActionPerformedBadgeUpdater, ActivityReturningStateNotify {


private val dbHandler: PediaDatabase = PediaDatabase(this)
private var mDrawer: Drawer? = null
private var filePath: String? = null
private var backupFileName: String? = null
private var listBt: MenuItem? = null
private var gridBt: MenuItem? = null
private var frontAppName: TextView? = null
private var buttonStatePref: SharedPreferences? = null
private var speedDialView: SpeedDialView? = null
private var trashNotesCount: String? = null
private var archiveNotesCount: String? = null
private var onLayoutChange: LayoutChangeListener? = null

private var newNoteCreated: Boolean = false //THIS IS THE BOOL

private lateinit var mAdView: AdView



companion object
{
    private const val LAYOUT_USER_PREF = "layout_preference"
}


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    onLayoutChange = NotesFrag()

    if(savedInstanceState == null) //prevents reloading fragment
    {
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.add(R.id.innerFrameLayout,NotesFrag()).commit()
    }



    trashNotesCount = dbHandler.trashedNotesCount().toString()
    archiveNotesCount = dbHandler.archivedNoteCount().toString()

    val drawerTrashBt: PrimaryDrawerItem = PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(1).withName("Trash Bin")
            .withIcon(R.drawable.delete_note_image)
            .withBadge(trashNotesCount)
            .withSelectedIcon(R.drawable.delete_drawer_selected)

    val drawerArchiveBt: PrimaryDrawerItem = PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(2).withName("Archive")
            .withIcon(R.drawable.archive_note_img)
            .withBadge(archiveNotesCount)
            .withSelectedIcon(R.drawable.archive_drawer_selected)

    val drawerNotesBt: PrimaryDrawerItem = PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(3).withName("Notes")
            .withIcon(R.drawable.notes_img)
            .withBadge(dbHandler.totalNotes().toString())
            .withSelectedIcon(R.drawable.notes_drawer_selected)

    val drawerLockedNotesBt: PrimaryDrawerItem = PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(4).withName("Locked Notes")
            .withIcon(R.drawable.lock_button)
            .withBadge("1")
            .withSelectedIcon(R.drawable.locked_drawer_selected)

    val drawerReminderNotesBt: PrimaryDrawerItem = PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(5).withName("Reminder Notes")
            .withIcon(R.drawable.reminder_notes)
            .withBadge("1")
            .withSelectedIcon(R.drawable.reminder_drawer_selected)

    val drawerFavouriteNotesBt: PrimaryDrawerItem = PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(6).withName("Favourite Notes")
            .withIcon(R.drawable.rate_app_star_img)
            .withBadge("1")
            .withSelectedIcon(R.drawable.favourite_drawer_selected)

    val drawerSettingsBt: PrimaryDrawerItem = PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(7).withName("Settings")
            .withIcon(R.drawable.settings_drawer)



      mDrawer = DrawerBuilder().withActivity(this)
            .withHeader(R.layout.navbar_header)
            .addDrawerItems(drawerNotesBt,drawerArchiveBt,drawerTrashBt,
                    drawerLockedNotesBt,drawerReminderNotesBt,
                    drawerFavouriteNotesBt,DividerDrawerItem(), drawerSettingsBt)

            .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(object: Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener{
                override fun onItemClick(view: View?, position: Int, drawerItem: IDrawerItem<*, *>?): Boolean {

                    when(position)
                    {
                        1 ->
                        {
                            frontAppName!!.text = "Wonder Notes"
                            speedDialView!!.show() //show again because traversing to other fragments hides it

                            val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            transaction.replace(R.id.innerFrameLayout, NotesFrag())
                            transaction.addToBackStack(null)
                            transaction.commit()

                        }

                        2 ->
                        {
                            speedDialView!!.hide()
                            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.innerFrameLayout,ArchiveFragment()).commit()
                        }

                        3 ->
                        {
                            frontAppName!!.text = "Trash"
                            speedDialView!!.hide()


                            fabLayoutBehaviourSetter(false)

                            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.innerFrameLayout, TrashFragment()).commit()
                        }
                        4 ->  Log.d("locked notes","1")

                        5 ->  Log.d("reminder","1")

                        6 ->  Log.d("favourite","1")
                    }

                    return false // false closes drawer on click
                }
            }).build()


    /*Below code handles swipe tabs adapter setting and displaying
     * and implements fragments to viewpager programitically */

  //  mainActivityViewPagerID.adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)

   // attachNotesFrag()




    //mainTabsID.setupWithViewPager(mainActivityViewPagerID)
    //mainTabsID.setTabTextColors(Color.DKGRAY, Color.parseColor("white"))




    val drawerOpener = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.drawerOpenImgBt)
    val noteCounterAsBt = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.showNotesCountID)




    drawerOpener.setOnClickListener { mDrawer!!.openDrawer() }
    noteCounterAsBt.setOnClickListener { mDrawer!!.openDrawer() }
    //navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)



    val customToolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarID)
      setSupportActionBar(customToolbar)


      supportActionBar!!.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false) //set main title off

       val toolbarTxtView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.toolbar_title)
         toolbarTxtView.visibility = View.GONE


    checkForStoragePermission()
}//on create




override fun onContextBarVisibilityChange(isVisible: Boolean) { //custom interface

    if(isVisible)
    {
        speedDialView!!.hide()
        fabLayoutBehaviourSetter(false) //remove scrolling behaviour

    }
    else
    {
        speedDialView!!.show()
        fabLayoutBehaviourSetter(true) //set scrolling behaviour
    }

}


override fun onReturnedToActivity(actionID: Int) { ///it just recieves value from ACTIVITY2 and assign its value to ACTIVTY1`s "newNoteCreated" varaible
    when(actionID)
    {
        3 ->
        {
            Log.d("INTERFACE","CALLED $actionID")
            newNoteCreated = true

            Log.d("INTERFACE","CALLED $newNoteCreated")
        }
    }
}
```

**REFERENCE ACTIVITY(ACTIVITY2)**
I am only including the part where interface sends data back to activity1 because the code of activity2 is very lengthy and will most likely confuse readers.

```
 onActivityReturningStateNotify = MainActivity()


 dbHandler!!.createNote(note)

                //onActionPerformedBadgeUpdater!!.onActionPerformed(3)
                onActivityReturningStateNotify!!.onReturnedToActivity(3)
```

**INTERFACE**

```
interface ActivityReturningStateNotify {

fun onReturnedToActivity(actionID: Int)
```

}

Comment: show how you define onActivityReturningStateNotify

Comment: I think you maybe confused on what an interface can do, to explain we need to see the actual object onActivityReturningStateNotify.  We see that Activity1 implements the interface.

Comment: I have added the interface code. I do not understand what you mean by "actual object"? Could you please clarify?

Comment: Ok,  so you are creating a new instance of MainActivity,  it's not the one that started your current activity.  In android,  as much as we would like to, you can't simply hold a reference to a prior activity and then communicate with it .  This would be great, but you can't do it

Comment: Okay, I get it now. So, what is the solution for it? What about broadcast listeners? If I can not communicate with my previous instance of the main activity that was holding broadcast listener, that means I would not be able to communicate that way as well?

Comment: I updated my answer,  using startActivityForResult is one of several ways to share data between activities.  I personally like to use SharedPreferences and write the data in one activity and then read it back in another activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are calling onReturnedToActivity() on a new instance of MainActivity, not the one you started from or the one that you will return to.

There are several ways to share data between activities,  one is to use startActivityForResult().

I think your problem however is that Activity1 will be stopped,  so you can't really send it data from Activity2.  You can however start Activity2 with `startActivityForResult` and return a result.
Here is the example from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).

Starting the activity.

```
const val PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 1  // The request code
...
private fun pickContact() {
    Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts")).also { pickContactIntent ->
        pickContactIntent.type = Phone.CONTENT_TYPE // Show user only contacts w/ phone numbers
        startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST)
    }
}
```

Getting the returned data.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // The user picked a contact.
            // The Intent's data Uri identifies which contact was selected.

            // Do something with the contact here (bigger example below)
        }
    }
}
```

Other schemes include a Global Singleton, launching activities with Intents,   or using SharedPreferences writting data in one activity and then reading it back in another.
If you do a search on `android share data between activities`  You will see there are various options on the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: Hi, just added the codes. However, I am trying to get my work done only through an interface(if possible). I know I can start activity for the result but in the future how data gets returned to activity1 will get more complex so hence trying to avoid "startActivityForResult". onReturnedToActivity() is my interface that is implemented in activity2 that sends data to activity1. I just do not understand why activity1 no longer accepts new data as long as it is not in the foreground and more particularly why it resets member variables back to their original data?

Comment: According to your updated answer, I am thinking to opt for singleton class to hold the data. I will try to implement it now. Thank you for your kind response!

Comment: remember accept the answer if answered your question.

Comment: BTW,  make sure you understand the implications of Android configuration changes, ie rotating a device,  it could have an affect even on the Singleton.

Comment: I am still a novice in android development and learning from my mistakes. My app opts 1 activity many fragments designs. I have (not a good way perhaps) prevented activity from reloading current holding fragments by checking if the saved instance was null then load the fragment otherwise don't.

Answer (score 0):

It is bad idea to assign Activity1 to Activity2 by interface, try to use in activity1 : `startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)` make whatever you want in activity2 and then call: `onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);` and in activity1 override the funtion : `onActivityResult()` and take the boolean data from the intent.

Comment: There are certain ways that a user can launch second activity without actually having to press a button and initiate startActivityForResult. There is a recycled view populated card views and when a user clicks on a card view it takes to the second activity. Which is why onActivityResult won't be called. It is a little complex the way data is handled and how the activity is launched which is the reason I  am avoiding it.

Comment: It doesn't matter where you click you cannot start activity without calling startActivity() so you can replace it with the startActivityForResult() , if you really not able to call properly startActivity() your architecture is pretty messed up so i would advise you to take some time to fix it before adding more mess.

Comment: I can not implement startActivityForResult() in my adapter

Comment: That true, and you shouldn't, what you can do is to implement onItemClickListener() in the activity who hold the adapter and call startActivity there. if you use RecyclerViewAdapter you can implement custom itemClickListener